# OkHttp Certificate pinning Error or default behavior?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, pinning, certificate-pinning

Recently, I've been testing the [certificate pinning](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-certificate-pinner/) implementation provided by [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) using version 4.9.0 + Retrofit 2.9.0; And I've noticed that the hash check is not conjunctive but rather disjunctive.

According to the example implementation the certificate chain of [publicobject.com](https://publicobject.com):

```
Peer certificate chain:
    sha256/afwiKY3RxoMmLkuRW1l7QsPZTJPwDS2pdDROQjXw8ig=: CN=publicobject.com, OU=PositiveSSL
    sha256/klO23nT2ehFDXCfx3eHTDRESMz3asj1muO+4aIdjiuY=: CN=COMODO RSA Secure Server CA
    sha256/grX4Ta9HpZx6tSHkmCrvpApTQGo67CYDnvprLg5yRME=: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
    sha256/lCppFqbkrlJ3EcVFAkeip0+44VaoJUymbnOaEUk7tEU=: CN=AddTrust External CA Root
```

If we change the certificate and we do so with the same provider and/or root as before, we would get something like:

```
Peer certificate chain:
    sha256/dklfnskvAAQFvandjfjASAFjvjvg45nbwskdvur5548=: CN=publicobject.com, OU=PositiveSSL
    sha256/klO23nT2ehFDXCfx3eHTDRESMz3asj1muO+4aIdjiuY=: CN=COMODO RSA Secure Server CA
    sha256/grX4Ta9HpZx6tSHkmCrvpApTQGo67CYDnvprLg5yRME=: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
    sha256/lCppFqbkrlJ3EcVFAkeip0+44VaoJUymbnOaEUk7tEU=: CN=AddTrust External CA Root
```

Only the first hash changes, naturally I would assume that communications with the site should stop working since our implementation now has an incorrect hash, but that is not the case because the other three are the same as before.

Is it my error when creating a new certificate?
Is this the correct behavior or an error?
Is there a way to check for all hashes in the chain to be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 4 certificates involved in that particular handshake, and OkHttp is happy if *any* of them match one of your signatures.

This means you can survive either of these operational events:

- changing your certificate authority (your organization public key stays the same)
- losing your public key and switching it out (the CA stays the same)

But if you change certificate authorities and you get a new public key, clients won't connect until you update their pins.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, so this is default behavior then, I would assume that there's no way to change it to a more restrictive check for all pins to match, correct? (Unless of course to request support for it and that it makes its way to the codebase)

Comment: Pin the leaf certificate if that’s your goal. It’s a bad goal though; if you leak the private key to that certificate your clients will either not be able to connect or will be forced to connect with a bad key.